# vba outlook macro not converting image files to pdf

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, export-to-pdf

i currently have the following VBA macro to export emails and attachements to pdf and merge to 1 pdf however some images files sometimes dont convert usually jpeg/png file

im a bit limited to what i can use since i cant install anything on my machine so have to use portable apps

```
'https://hinchley.net/articles/a-macro-to-export-multiple-emails-and-their-attachments-from-microsoft-outlook-to-a-single-pdf
' Purpose: Save selected emails, and their attachments, to a PDF.

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Declare Function CoAllowSetForegroundWindow Lib "ole32.dll" (ByVal pUnk As Object, ByVal lpvReserved As Long) As Long

Dim Namespace As Namespace
Dim FileSystemObject As FileSystemObject
Dim SelectedEmails As Selection
Dim SavedFiles As Collection
Dim FilesToMerge As Collection
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application



' Regular expressions defining the attachments that will be processed.
' All other attachments will be ignored.
Const ExcelExtensionsRegExp = "^(xl(s|sx|sm|t|tm|tx))$"
Const ImageExtensionsRegExp = "^(JPG|webp|jpg|jepg|png|gif|bmp|tiff?)$"
Const OtherExtensionsRegExp = "^(do(c|cx|cm|t|tm|tx)|pdf|txt)$"
Const MessageExtensionsRegExp = "^(msg)$"

Sub ExportToPdf()
  ' Exit if the user has not selected at least one email.
  If (Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0) Then
    MsgBox "Please select one or more emails.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Set Namespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set FileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set SelectedEmails = Outlook.ActiveExplorer.Selection

  Set SavedFiles = New Collection
  Set FilesToMerge = New Collection

  Set WordApp = New Word.Application
  WordApp.Visible = False

  ' Allow Word to take focus. Required to ensure the Save As dialog comes to the foreground.
  CoAllowSetForegroundWindow WordApp, 0

  ' Backup the "warn before saving" option.
  WarnBeforeSaveOption = WordApp.Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup

  ' Disable the option.
  WordApp.Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup = False

  Set ExcelApp = Nothing

  ' The path where the generated PDF will be saved.
  pdfPath = "C:\_Mail\temp\"

  ' Exit if no path is specified for saving the PDF.
  ' This will occur if the user closes the 'File Save As' dialog without providing a valid path.
  If pdfPath = "" Then
    ' Word is used to display the 'File Save As' dialog.
    ' Close Word before exiting.
    WordApp.Quit
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' The path to the folder where all temporary documents, and the final PDF, will be saved.
  SavePath = Left(pdfPath, InStrRev(pdfPath, "\"))

  ' Initialise the progress bar component.
  ProgressBox.Show
  ProgressBox.Increment 0, "Exportando..."

  ' Save the selected emails, and their attachments, to the file system.
  SaveEmails SelectedEmails, SavePath

  ' Convert each of the saved files to PDF documents.
  ConvertDocumentsToPdf

  ' Merge the PDF documents into a single PDF document.
  'MergePdfDocuments PdfPath
  MergePDFs

  ' Indicate the export is complete.
  ProgressBox.Increment 100, "Completo!"

  ' Show the completion dialog for 1 second.
  Sleep 1000
  ProgressBox.Hide
DeleteFolderContents
  ' Reinstate the old "warn before save" option.
  WordApp.Options.WarnBeforeSavingPrintingSendingMarkup = WarnBeforeSaveOption

  ' Close Word (and Excel, if it was used to process attachments).
  WordApp.Quit
  If Not (ExcelApp Is Nothing) Then
    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    ExcelApp.Quit
  End If

  ' Clean up.
  Set SavedFiles = Nothing
  Set FilesToMerge = Nothing
  Set SelectedEmails = Nothing
  Set FileSystemObject = Nothing
  Set Namespace = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetPdfPath()
  ' The easiest way to retrieve a file save path is via the GetSaveAsFilename method in Excel.
  ' Unfortunately, this method isn't available in Word.
  ' As this macro always requires Word, but only requires Excel when exporting an Excel attachment,
  ' it makes sense to avoid using Excel to retrieve the file save path.
  ' Hence we use the (slightly more convoluted) FileDialog method.
  Set Dialog = WordApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
  With Dialog
    .InitialFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\"
    .FilterIndex = 7 ' *.pdf - the 7th option in the drop down list box of file formats.
    .Title = "Save As"
    If .Show <> 0 Then
      GetPdfPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
      GetPdfPath = ""
    End If
  End With
End Function

Private Sub SaveEmails(SelectedEmails, SavePath)
  ' Used to update the progress bar.
  Counter = 0

  ' Iterate through each of the selected emails.
  For Each SelectedEmail In SelectedEmails
    ' Update the progress indicator (pausing each time for 250ms to ensure the progression is noticeable).
    ProgressBox.Increment (Counter / SelectedEmails.Count) * 100, "Exportando..."
    Sleep 250

    ' Retrieve the details of the current email.
    EntryID = SelectedEmail.EntryID
    Set Email = Namespace.GetItemFromID(EntryID)

    SaveEmail Email, SavePath

    ' Increment the counter that is used to update the progress indicator.
    Counter = Counter + 1

    Set Email = Nothing
  Next SelectedEmail
End Sub

Private Sub SaveEmail(Email, SavePath)
  ' The full path used for saving the email to the file system.
  ' The document name is based on the time the email was received.
  Path = SavePath & "1-EMAIL" & (Int(Rnd * 100000)) & Format(Email.CreationTime, "hhmmss-dd-MM-yyyy") & ".doc"

  ' Delete any previous copy of the email from the file system.
  ' This is only necessary if the email was previously exported, but not properly cleaned up (e.g. the previous export failed).
  If FileSystemObject.FileExists(Path) Then
    FileSystemObject.DeleteFile Path
  End If

  ' Record (in a collection named SaveFiles) the path to the saved email.
  ' This collection will be subsequently used to retrieve a list of the files that need to be merged.
  SavedFiles.Add Path

  ' Save the email to the file system.
  Email.SaveAs Path, olDoc

  ' Resize images in the email.
  Set Document = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=Path, Visible:=False)
  If Document.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
    ResizeImages Document
  End If
  Document.SaveAs2 Path, wdFormatXMLDocument
  Document.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges, wdOriginalDocumentFormat, False

  ' The following block is only executed if the email includes attachments.
  If Email.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
    ' Iterate through all attachments.
    For Each Attachment In Email.Attachments
      ' Extract the extension of each attachment.
      Extension = GetFileExtension(Attachment.FileName)

      ' Inline images are saved with the email, and do not need to be processed as separate attachments.
      If IsEmbeddedAttachment(Attachment) And IsImage(Extension) Then
        GoTo NextIteration
      End If

      ' Only attachments matching the whitelist of approved types are processed.
      If IsValidAttachment(Extension) Then
        ' The attachment is saved to the file system (using the attachment file name).
        AttachmentPath = Truncate(SavePath & "2-anexo" & (Int(Rnd * 100000)) & Attachment.FileName)
        Attachment.SaveAsFile AttachmentPath

        ' Additional processing is applied to Excel attachments.
        If IsExcelDocument(Extension) Then
          ' Start Excel if it isn't already running (i.e. this is the first Excel attachment).
          If ExcelApp Is Nothing Then
            Set ExcelApp = New Excel.Application
            ExcelApp.Visible = False
            ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
          End If

          ' The path to the new Word document that will be used for storing the content within the Excel document.
          FilePath = Truncate(GetBaseFilePath(AttachmentPath) & (Int(Rnd * 100000)) & ".docx")

          ' Create a new blank Word document.
          Set TempDocument = WordApp.Documents.Add("Normal", False, wdNewBlankDocument, False)

          ' Open the Excel document.
          Set Workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(AttachmentPath)

          ' Iterate through all worksheets in the Excel document.
          For Each Worksheet In Workbook.Worksheets
            ' Copy the content within the worksheet.
            Worksheet.UsedRange.Copy

            ' Add a new section to the target Word document.
            Set Section = TempDocument.Sections.Add

            ' Paste the copied content into the Word document.
            Section.Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
          Next Worksheet

          ' Delete the first section of the temporary Word document.
          ' This removes the blank page that is created at the beginning of the document when the first section is added.
          TempDocument.Sections.Item(1).Range.Delete wdCharacter, 1

          ' Save the temporary Word document.
          TempDocument.SaveAs2 FilePath, wdFormatXMLDocument
          TempDocument.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges, wdOriginalDocumentFormat, False

          ' Close and then delete the Excel document.
          Workbook.Close False
          Kill AttachmentPath

          ' The attachment path is no longer the path to the saved Excel document;
          ' it's now the path to the Word document into which the Excel content was copied.
          AttachmentPath = FilePath
        ElseIf IsEmailMsg(Extension) Then
          ' Attachment is an Msg.
          Set Msg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(AttachmentPath)
          SaveEmail Msg, SavePath
          Kill AttachmentPath

          GoTo NextIteration
        End If

        ' Record the path to the saved attachment.
        SavedFiles.Add AttachmentPath
      End If

NextIteration:
    Next Attachment
  End If
End Sub

'Helper function to ensure path lengths are unique and don't exceed 250 characters.
Function Truncate(Path)
  ' Maximum number of characters in a file path.
  MaxPathLength = 250

  ' Length of current path.
  PathLength = Len(Path)

  If PathLength > MaxPathLength Then
    Extension = GetFileExtension(Path)
    ' Truncate base file path such that when the extension is re-added, the max path length is not exceeded.
    Truncate = Left(GetBaseFilePath(Path), MaxPathLength - Len(Extension) + 1) & "." & Extension
  Else
    Truncate = Path
  End If
End Function

' Helper function to retrieve the extension of a file. e.g. FooBar.pdf = pdf
Function GetFileExtension(FileName)
  GetFileExtension = LCase(FileSystemObject.GetExtensionName(FileName))
End Function

' Helper function to check if an attachment is embedded (OLE) within an email.
' We typically want to ignore embedded attachments as they are automatically included when an email is saved.
Function IsEmbeddedAttachment(Attachment)
  Set PropertyAccessor = Attachment.PropertyAccessor
  Property = PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E")
  IsEmbeddedAttachment = InStr(1, Property, "@")
End Function

' Helper function to check if a string (subject) matches a regular expression pattern.
Function TestRegExp(Subject, Pattern)
  Set RegExp = New RegExp
  With RegExp
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = Pattern
  End With
  TestRegExp = RegExp.Test(Subject)
End Function

' Helper function to check if an attachment is an image (based on file extension).
Function IsImage(Extension)
  IsImage = TestRegExp(Extension, ImageExtensionsRegExp)
End Function

' Helper function to check if an attachment is an Excel document (based on file extension).
Function IsExcelDocument(Extension)
  IsExcelDocument = TestRegExp(Extension, ExcelExtensionsRegExp)
End Function

' Helper function to check if an attachment is an Outlook email (based on file extension).
Function IsEmailMsg(Extension)
  IsEmailMsg = TestRegExp(Extension, MessageExtensionsRegExp)
End Function

' Helper function to check if an attachment, other than an image or Excel document, is whitelisted (based on file extension).
Function IsOtherValidDocument(Extension)
  IsOtherValidDocument = TestRegExp(Extension, OtherExtensionsRegExp)
End Function

' Helper function to check if an attachment is a PDF (based on file extension).
Function IsPdfDocument(Path)
  IsPdfDocument = TestRegExp(Path, "\.pdf$")
End Function

' Helper function to check if an attachment is whitelisted (based on file extension).
Function IsValidAttachment(Extension)
  IsValidAttachment = IsImage(Extension) Or IsExcelDocument(Extension) Or IsEmailMsg(Extension) Or IsOtherValidDocument(Extension)
End Function

' Helper function to get the path to a file without the file's extension.
Function GetBaseFilePath(Path)
  Extension = "." & GetFileExtension(Path)
  GetBaseFilePath = Replace(Path, Extension, "")
End Function

' Used to convert all emails and their associated attachments to PDF documents.
Private Sub ConvertDocumentsToPdf()
  ' Initialise the progress bar component.
  ' This resets the progress bar after saving emails and attachments to the file system.
  ProgressBox.Increment 0, "Convertendo..."
  Counter = 0

  ' Iterate through the emails and attachments that were saved to the file system.
  For Each SavedFile In SavedFiles
    ProgressBox.Increment (Counter / SavedFiles.Count) * 100, "Convertendo..."
    Sleep 250

    ' No processing required for native PDF document.
    If IsPdfDocument(SavedFile) Then
      FilesToMerge.Add SavedFile
    Else
      NewPdfPath = GetBaseFilePath(SavedFile) & ".pdf"

      ' Check if the saved document is an image.
      If IsImage(GetFileExtension(SavedFile)) Then
        ' Create a new blank Word document.
        Set Document = WordApp.Documents.Add("Normal", False, wdNewBlankDocument, False)

        ' Insert the image as a shape into the new consolidated document.
        InsertImage SavedFile, Document
      Else
        ' Open the document in Word.
        Set Document = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=SavedFile, Visible:=False)
      End If

      ' Save the Word document as a PDF.
      Document.SaveAs2 NewPdfPath, wdFormatPDF

      ' Close Word.
      Document.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges, wdOriginalDocumentFormat, False

      ' Store the path to the collection of PDF documents to be merged.
      FilesToMerge.Add NewPdfPath

      ' Delete the saved document after it has been converted to a PDF.
      Kill SavedFile
    End If

    Counter = Counter + 1
  Next SavedFile
End Sub

' Resize inline images so that they don't extend beyond the borders of the page.
Sub ResizeImages(Document)
  ' Get page dimensions. Give some wiggle room.
  PageHeight = Document.PageSetup.PageHeight - (Document.PageSetup.TopMargin + Document.PageSetup.BottomMargin + 50)
  PageWidth = Document.PageSetup.PageWidth - (Document.PageSetup.LeftMargin + Document.PageSetup.RightMargin + Document.PageSetup.Gutter + 50)

  For I = 1 To Document.InlineShapes.Count
    ' Check if the current shape is a picture.
    If Document.InlineShapes.Item(I).Type = wdInlineShapePicture Or Document.InlineShapes.Item(I).Type = wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture Then
      Set Shape = Document.InlineShapes.Item(I)
      Shape.Range.Select
      Shape.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse

      ' Constrain the shape dimensions to fit within the page.
      If (Shape.Width > PageWidth) Then
        If ((PageWidth / Shape.Width) * Shape.Height > PageHeight) Then
          Shape.Width = PageHeight / Shape.Height * PageWidth
          Shape.Height = PageHeight
        Else
          Shape.Width = PageWidth
          Shape.Height = (PageWidth / Shape.Width) * Shape.Height
        End If
      ElseIf (Shape.Height > PageHeight) Then
        Shape.Width = PageHeight / Shape.Height * Shape.Width
        Shape.Height = PageHeight
      End If

      Shape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
    End If
  Next I
End Sub

' Helper function to insert an image into a document.
Private Sub InsertImage(FileName, Document)
  ' Ensure the target document is active.
  Document.Activate

  ' Insert the source image into the target document as an inline shape.
  Set Shape = Document.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
End Sub

Private Sub MergePDFs()
Dim folderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim strOutputFolderPath As String
Dim QPDFPath As String
Dim QPDFCommand As String
Dim strHeaderText As String

'Set the folder path where the PDF files are located
folderPath = "C:\_Mail\temp\"

' Prompt the user to enter the custom text for the header
    strHeaderText = InputBox("Insira Numero de Registo:")
    
' Set the output file path and filename using the custom text entered by the user
   FileName = "" & strHeaderText & ".pdf"



'Set the output folder path where the merged PDF file will be saved
strOutputFolderPath = "C:\_Mail\"

'Set the path to the QPDF executable
QPDFPath = "C:\qpdf-11.3.0-msvc64\qpdf-11.3.0-msvc64\bin\qpdf.exe"

'Build the QPDF command to merge all PDF files in the folder
QPDFCommand = QPDFPath & " --empty --pages " & folderPath & "*.pdf" & " -- " & " " & strOutputFolderPath & FileName

'Execute the QPDF command
Shell QPDFCommand, vbHide


'MsgBox "PDF files merged successfully!"

End Sub
Private Sub DeleteFolderContents()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    
    ' Set the folder path
    folderPath = "C:\_Mail\temp"
    
    ' Create a FileSystemObject
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Get the folder object
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folderPath)
    
    ' Loop through each file in the folder and delete it
    For Each file In folder.Files
        file.Delete
    Next file
    
    ' Clean up
    Set file = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

convert all images to pdf

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the email as a Word document and then opening the saved document using Word object model, you can use the [Inspector.WordEditor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.wordeditor) property which returns the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. Use the [GetInspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getinspector) method which returns an `Inspector` object that represents an inspector initialized to contain the specified item. For example:

```
 'GetInspector property returns Inspector 
 Set myInspector = myItem.GetInspector 
 'Obtain the Word.Document for the Inspector 
 Set wdDoc = myInspector.WordEditor 
 If Not (wdDoc Is Nothing) Then 
   'Use the Range object to insert text 
   Set wdRange = wdDoc.Range(0, wdDoc.Characters.Count) 
   wdRange.InsertAfter ("Hello world!") 
 End If
```

The Word object model provides the [Document.ExportAsFixedFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.exportasfixedformat) method which saves a document in PDF or XPS format.